# Why for this equation, convergence is not guaranteed with steepest descent methods?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I uses soft svm recently. I found a good slide from http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281B-spring04/lectures/lec6.pdf.

For the soft svm, suppose there are $n$ samples. $f(x_i)=w^Tx_i+b$, $x_i$ is the features of the $i^th$ sample, and $y_i$ is its label. 
$$\min_w \frac{1}{2}w^Tw+ C\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\max{(0,1-y_if(x_i))}$$

The slides says 'the second term is piece-wise linear and convex '. I can understand that.
But I am confused which 'convergence is not guaranteed with steepest descent methods.' as it says.

I think for a convex function, using steepest descent method can reach the global minimum.

Comment: Should the second term depend on $w$?  I think the issue is that the objective function isn't differentiable, but gradient descent assumes a differentiable objective function.  To minimize this objective you need a method that can handle a non-differentiable objective function.

Comment: @littleO, hi, thank you for your answer. But as far as I know, subgradient descent can handle such a problem and it converges/